# Steam does not recognize I launched Civ VI

Tags: steam, civilization-6

When I launch a game my status changes from "Online" to "In-Game".
Except when I launch Civilization VI. Then, nothing happens.
I think achievement progress also doesn't work. The hours I play are recorded.

I've reinstalled both Steam and Civilization VI. Nothing changed.

When I go to my profile and visit my achievement progress I get: "There was a failure loading user game stats."

Comment: Try exiting steam and launching civ vi by using the exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a problem with Steam Overlay. If you are closing the Steam window after launching the game, try leaving it open. If that doesn't work, go to your SteamDIR while in game and run GameOverlayUI.exe.

Comment: Alternatively (this might be a new feature since October 2016), you can right-click the game in your library, go to 'Properties', and, while in the 'General' tab, deselect 'Enable the Steam Overlay while in-game'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try verifying the game cache. I had a similar problem with CSGO and it worked (directx problem).

Comment: If reinstalling doesn't work, this probably won't, either.